# IE7 jQuery Sortable bug?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create a 3 column page with jQuery where users can move boxes between the three columns (something simular to iGoogle).  In firefox and safari the dragging works perfectly fine.  In IE7, once you drag a box once it works fine but then that box cannot be moved after that.  I've tried re-applying the jQuery Sortable plugin to any moved box again but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas anyone?

Here's the code: http://www.marksblogg.com/dragging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets

Does this work in IE7?

Sorry I cannot test it I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Yeah, that works just fine in IE7.  I'm wondering if it's a combination of my scripts that's breaking something.  I've spent ages on this and I just can't see quite what it is.

Comment: Sorry, I can see the library being used there is different from what I'm using.  I put together a quick demo with that one and it looks to be working in IE7 nicely (but with other new bugs but that's besides the point).  Thanks for pointing that one out.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for giving me some rep. Cheers! BTW, IE sucks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a know bug with sortable on IE6 and IE7.
Check out if your parent item is set in a relative position.
If so, that might be the cause...